# How can I process ActiveX in Vaadin

Tags: javascript, vaadin, activex

I want to start "Chrome.exe" by javaScript using ActiveXObject,However it doesn't work in Vaadin.
Anyone has some ideas ? Thanks!

```
button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(final ClickEvent event) {
            try {
                UI.getCurrent().getPage().getJavaScript().execute(getScript());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


public String getScript() {
    StringBuilder array = new StringBuilder();
    array.append("try {");
    array.append("var wsh = new ActiveXObject(\"WScript.shell\");");
    array.append("alert('test');");
    array.append("var reg = wsh.RegRead('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\chrome.exe\\');");
    // array.append("alert(reg);");
    array.append("wsh.Run(reg+'http://stackoverflow.com'); ");
    array.append(" wsh=null;");
    array.append("} catch (e) {");
    array.append("alert(e);");
    array.append("return false;");
    array.append("}");
    // array.append("}");
    // array.append("}");

    return array.toString();
}
```

Comment: Is alert executed?

Comment: thanks, i hava fixed it . There is no need to read registry. use 'wsh.Run(" \" chrome.exe http://stackoverflow.com\"'); '